# codeigniter query database error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I implemented a simple query in my model:

```
$condition = "id='$user_id' AND (role='admin' OR role='manager' OR role='staff')" ;
$this->db->select("password,ref_id,role");
$this->db->from("user");
$this->db->where($condition);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->row_array();
```

However, the following error occurred:

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'id='1'' in 'where clause'

SELECT `password`, `ref_id`, `role` FROM (`user`) WHERE `id='1'` AND (role='customer' OR role='supplier')

Filename: D:\MYSERVER\wamp\www\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

So what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this one:

```
$this->db->where($condition, NULL, false);
```

In the above syntax, the first one is for the `condition`, second parameter is for the `value` which is `NULL` here, and third is for escaping the string(default is true).

Comment: could you please explain the meaning of 2nd and 3rd parameter?

Comment: the first one is for the name, second parameter is for the value and third is for escaping the string(default is true).

Comment: See how `id='1'` CI is trying to escape the string and thats why this error is happening.

Comment: if this answer is correct and did helped you please choose this as best answer

Comment: @user3453318 If your question has been answered, please [mark the answer that you feel best addressed your question as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), rather than posting a comment thanking the answerer. Once you have at least 15 rep, you can also [upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) the accepted answer and any other answers you found useful.

Comment: @Nil'z Can you please add the explanations to the answer? It's in the Low Quality Posts review queue because it's just one line of code with no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select("password,ref_id,role");
$this->db->from("user");
$this->db->where('id', $user_id);
$this->db->where('role', 'manager');
$this->db->where_or('role', 'staff');
```

**OR** in case of your code, the where won't work. If you are adding a sql statement in where, you have to pass other parameters also. Try below -

```
$this->db->where($condition, NULL, FALSE);
```